# Grails rendering a partial template on changes in select

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I just want to render a partial template when a SELECT is changed. I tried onchange and remotFunction but it will not compile.

In the gsp I've written:

```
<g:select name="sawMill" from="${prodBuffer}" value="" onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'availableProducts')}"/>
```

and in the controller:

```
def availableProducts() {
    render(template:"AvailableProductData", model:[prodBuffer: getBufferList()])
}
```

The error:

```
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
    Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/orders_and_Store/list.gsp:154] Error executing tag <g:form>: Error evaluating expression [remoteFunction(action: 'availableProducts')] on line [24]: No signature of method: D__Grails_projects_torntrading_grails_app_views_orders_and_Store_list_gsp.remoteFunction() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[action:availableProducts]]
Caused by
    No signature of method: D__Grails_projects_torntrading_grails_app_views_orders_and_Store_list_gsp.remoteFunction() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[action:availableProducts]]
```

I've seen a lot of different solutions but they are more complex, I just want to render a piece of gsp when the select changes and I don't think I need any parameters.

Comment: If you're using Grails 3, you have to add this dependency (not recommended) to your app https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/ajax-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Grails are you using?

remoteFunction was deprecated in 2.4.x

You can use your own ajax function like:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function availableProducts(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'${g.createLink( controller:'product', action:'availableProducts' )}',
                data: [sawMill],
                type: 'get'
        }).success( function ( data ) { $( '#divToUpdate' ).html( data ); });
}
    </script>
<body>
    <g:select name="sawMill" from="${millList}" value="" onchange="availableProducts()"/>

    <div id="divToUpdate"></div>
</body>
```

I've assumed your controller is named productController, change this in the createLink statement if not.

You have to tell the function what area of the screen you're going to update with your template, in this case we're updating a div with id divToUpdate, again change to fit your gsp.

The controller should work okay as is assuming you have a template named _AvailableProductData in the same directory as the other gsp files for this controller.

Comment: That worked, the error is gone and the page renders but it didn't work as I expected. I wanted to use the selected sawMill to be used in a filter like

Comment: That worked, the error is gone and the page renders but it didn't work as I expected. I wanted to use the selected sawMill to be used in a filter like <g:each in="${prodBuffer.findAll{it.sawMill == sawMill}}" status="i" var="pb"> But that didn't happen, the sawMill-parameter is empty and I don't know how to get the selected value to the filter.

Comment: Updated answer to ensure sawMill value is sent to availableProducts action, you will be able to retrieve with params.sawMill now.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!